# Code behind for Infopath Initiation/Association Form

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath, visual-studio

Is it possible to have a c# file act as a code behind file for an infopath form? Just like you do for forms in aspx.
Especially I would like to be able to execute code on page_load for an infopath form and pre populate or modify the fields.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For browser-based Infopath forms (the ones requirng Infopath Forms Services of entrprise/paid Sharepoint Server) the custom code is impossible.

The custom (C#, VB.NET) code is possible for client (Infopath Filler 2010) forms.
And kind of, code-behind, since these forms cannot be rendered in a browser.
And rather as plugin code to black-box infopath Filler internals but not of the forms themselves.